# Confirm Facebook Post Exist

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a scenario within our iPhone App where people post things on their Facebook wall through our App. User's signup to our App. At a certain action, they post something on their Facebook wall and we want to track if this post will still exist after a certain time.

Once they signup to our App, they will either select as "Public" or "Friends" when they download our App. Is it possible to track from our end whether a certain post still exist or not?

Is there anything on the Facebook account settings as a user to disallow this to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post a feed, a `post-id` in returned in response. You can make a call using Graph API: `\GET /{post-id}`. If the post still exists, it'll return you all the details of the post but if not it will return the `error` in the response.

But, according to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#read) of `/user/feed`,

> A **user access token** with **`read_stream`** permission is required.

Now this will make the things a bit complicated. Since a user token is valid for only few hours, you have to extend it (validity: 60days) and save it at your end. Also, `read_stream` perms is required.

To know more about extending the token and refreshing it again, see the "Expiration and Extending Tokens" section here: [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending).

Comment: thank you Sahil for the info. However, does the user on his end needs to permit anything on his end to allow the App to check whether the post still exist or not? What I mean is that users on Facebook have the ability to set their postings on Only Me, Public and Friends. Our goal here is to see if the post that is made by one  of our users still exist or not, regardless any restriction set by the user.

Comment: Privacy doent matter. If you get response for /postid that means the post still exists. That's it